# Trying to construct a smooth inverse for a smooth map I know to be a diffeomorphism.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and $\text{Fr}_{GL}(M)$ be the frame bundle. Let $\rho$
be the standard representation of $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am trying to show that the associated vector bundle $E=\text{Fr}_{GL}(M)\times_\rho \mathbb{R}^n$ is isomorphic to $TM$. I have shown that the map:

$$\begin{align}
F:E&\longrightarrow TM\\
 [(v_1,\dots,v_n)_p,(x^1,\dots,x^n)]&\longmapsto v_ix^i
\end{align}$$
where $(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$ is a frame for $T_pM$ and $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ is some vector in
$\mathbb{R}^n$. I have already shown that this map is smooth, well defined, and satisfies:
$$
\begin{align}
\pi_{TM}\circ F=\pi_{E}
\end{align}
$$
I am now trying to construct a smooth inverse. My thinking is that I can just choose any frame for $T_pM$, and then send $v\in T_pM$ to an $n$-tuple in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with that frame. In particular, each point is contained in some chart so I was thinking:
$$
\begin{align}
F^{-1}:TM&\longrightarrow E\\
       (p,w)&\longmapsto[D_{\phi(p)}\phi^{-1},D_{p}\phi(w)]
\end{align}
$$
but something about this feels sketchy. I am pretty sure it is smooth, as I have already showed earlier that the map $s:U\rightarrow \text{Fr}_{GL}(M)$  given by $s(p)=D_{\phi(p)}\phi^{-1}$ is smooth, and and since the map $\text{Fr}_{GL}(M)\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow E$ is smooth. I believe it also independent the choice of chart,
as if $\psi$ is another chart containing $p$, then $D_{p}\phi\circ D_{\psi(p)}\psi^{-1}\in GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$, so:
$$\begin{align}
[D_{\phi(p)}\phi^{-1},D_{\phi(p)}\phi(w)]=&[D_{\phi(p)}\phi^{-1}\cdot(D_{p}\phi\circ D_{\psi(p)}\psi^{-1}) ,(D_{p}\psi\circ D_{\phi(p)}\phi^{-1})\circ D_{p}\phi(w)]\\
=&[D_{\psi(p)}\psi^{-1},D_{p}\psi(w)]
\end{align}$$
Is this right line of thinking or no? Any clarification or help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no need to work with trivializations. You've defined a bundle map $F$ that maps $M$ to itself by the identity map. It now suffices to show that the restriction of $F$ to any fiber of $E$ is a linear isomorphism $F_x: E_x \rightarrow T_xM$. It suffices to check that the kernel is $\{0\}$ and the map is surjective.

Comment: Oh I see, that’s much cleverer. Does what I did work though?

Comment: Dunno. But try to keep in mind that a lot of differential geometry, especially bundle maps, is really just doing abstract linear algebra on each fiber. This helps you avoid dealing with trivializations.

Comment: I’ll keep that in mind thank you. I’m still wondering if this is a possible route though.